# how can I do make MKMapView's pin moving on Photo Album Places view of ios4

Tags: iphone, animation, ios4, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

In iOS4's photo album place,
the photo-pins join and split each others when the map is zoomed out and in.

It's awesome experience! and I want to use same thing on my apps.

I guess, it should not be one of MapKit.

does anybody know that how can i do this?

Comment: I feel like I've read this same question about 5 times in the last 2 weeks.